# Creating a Sandbox for questions

Tags: feature-request

Due to a recent influx of low-quality questions on this site I think we should have a sandbox on this site.

Should we create a sandbox in this meta site, or is the stuff we have here enough?

Comment: What _"low-quality questions"_ are you referring to? How are they low quality, and according to whom? _"this site"_, do you refer to "meta" or to the main site? What's a sandbox for and why do we need it?

Comment: Is the fluff text in this question meant to be ironic then?

Comment: @Pikalek Yes, you reason correctly(padding words so i can get past the character limit)

Comment: It’s really unclear what you are proposing — both what you see as the problem and what you think the solution should be.

Answer (score 1):

In part, this is what the [review queue](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/review) is for. Special attention is called out toward helping new users.

If we had as much traffic as Stack Overflow, we might also have a [triage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/triage/info), but that's not yet needed here.

In my experience, the current system is already really effective at actual spam (ads & self promotion). After that, there are reputation & badge incentives to encourage everyone to edit posts.

Keep in mind that most users are not intentionally making bad posts. Mobiles aren't the most elegant way for submitting questions, but that's all some users have to work with. English is not a universal language. even in places where it is a default language, some use it better than others.

The barrier you propose strikes me as being at odds with the 'be friendly' attitude & [code of conduct](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), specifically:

> building a community where all people feel welcome and can
>   participate, regardless of expertise

Asking good questions, adapting to our norms & observing our protocols are skills that improve with practice & support from other community members.

Comment: This assumes we're talking about GDSE. I'm less familiar with how questions on meta-GDSE are dealt with.

Comment: This is more for users that are unsure that their posts are low quality or not

Comment: We are talking about GDSE

Answer (score 1):

We don't need this.

> Game Development Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional and independent game developers. It's built and run *by you* as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about game development. ([Source](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour))

StackExchange sites already have all (well, most likely 'most of') the tools required for moderation by the community. This includes

- using comments to tell users that ask how they can improve their questions (available to users who have 50 rep)
- proposing edits to questions (they get in a review queue for users with less that 1000 rep)
- vote up to indicate that the question is good, useful and well formatted (available to users with 15 rep
- vote down to indicate that questions are not useful, bad or lacking in effort (available for users with 125 rep)
- possibility to vote to close questions (for users with 3000 rep)
- multiple review queues to make sure the questions and answers on the site are of great quality.
- ...and [a lot more](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

The site is made in such a way that it will allow users to fail a bit and learn from it before preventing them from posting trash on the site.

If you're really worried about if a question fits well on the main site, either ask it there and wait for feedback and *learn from it*, or ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) and see the reaction of the users there.

Finally, from my own experience, questions asked in meta that should have been asked on the site instead are generally from users trying to evade a question ban on the main site. We won't open the door to it.